# Billing Agreements for non-PayPal customers

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

Can *Billing Agreements* be created for users that don't have PayPal accounts (i.e. paying via Express Checkout directly with Credit Card)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the person is using Express Checkout to setup a recurring payment profile or billing agreement they will need a PayPal account or they can create one during the checkout.

The only way to use billing agreement (reference transactions) or recurring payments with credit cards directly is to use Enhanced Subscriptions for Payments Standard, Payments Advanced with Recurring Billing, or Payments Pro with Recurring Billing.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Would the Pro option require us to manage credit cards ourselves (and hence be PCI compliant)?

Comment: Pro allows you to process cards directly, yes, so you would need an SSL to secure that transaction.  You wouldn't have to store any credit card numbers or anything in your database, though.  PayPal's system will still handle all of that and you can run reference transactions using DoReferenceTransaction the same way you would with Express Checkout billing agreements.